# PhantomJS not working when published items present except in c drive c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

*When I execute process from c drive it works fine but when I execute process from other drive i.e "D:" it shows Exception*

**Exception : File not found Sample.PDF**

Phantom first create pdf and then it write that pdf on MemoryStream after that  it show that on browser then delete this pdf..

In D drive it cant create pdf thats why it shows file not found . I only want to know that why it cant create on d drive its cmd rights issue or any thing else ..?

Kindly give me the right solution I am stuck on this.

```
    private byte[] DoWhile(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        bool fail = true;

        while (fail)
        {
            try
            {

                    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                        file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                    }

                    fail = false;


            }
            catch
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: The exception message tells you all you need to know `"Exception : File not found Sample.PDF"` - this indicates that the filepath is incorrect, verify that it points to the correct location. Use the debugger...

Comment: You dont check the file is there - have you copied it?

Comment: May I also add that this has nothing to do with PhantomJS whatsoever. Not even seen once in the code.

Comment: #DGibbs Debugger doesn't work on it when i click print button it goes in do while loop and loader comes infront ..

Comment: @ SimpleVar dude this is also a question why phantom cant create pdf , it creates when its deployed in c drive inshort it only works in c drive . i dont know what to do now :(

Comment: Use absolute path for `filePath` variable like **D:\myfolder\Sample.PDF**

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna Path is correct i checked it all the time 

cd D:\tfs Projects\Phantomjs\ & phantomjs rasterize.js  D:\tfs Projects\1457336246.31819_23.html Sample.pdf "A4" 

Process start with that command

Comment: Looks like the working directory (directory where you are running PhantomJS) is **D:\tfs Projects\Phantomjs** but the file path is **D:\tfs Projects\Sample.PDF**.  Could you please check it? Then [edit] your question by adding full absolute paths of working directory and input file.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna OK . i tell you the logic phantom first create pdf and then it write that pdf on MemoryStream  after that it delete  the pdf file and show the on browser .. 
in D drive it cant create pdf thats why it shows file not found . 
i only want to know that why it cant create on d drive its cmd rights issue or any thing else ..?